# "Import React from 'react' " not working getting : "Reference error, can't find variable require'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm following a react tutorial on scribe on react basics. My js was loading with the react and ReactDOM cdn before I added the import statements after adding them they no longer work (i.e the webpage is not loading the js) as in the tutorial.

Error Message: *[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require Global Code (Script Element 1:3)*

> **Here are my js files:**

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import "../index.css";

function MainContent() {
  return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <h1>Why React?</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur,
        natus delectus porro quos ad vero obcaecati velit dignissimos voluptatum
        debitis.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function OtherContent() {
  return (
    <div className="other-content">
      <h2>This is why i love React</h2>

      <ol>
        <li>It is declarative</li>
        <li>It is a very hireable skill</li>
        <li>It is useful in repeating code</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}

const page = (
  <div>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <MainContent></MainContent>
    <OtherContent></OtherContent>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(page, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="nav-icon">
        <span>
          <img src="./react-logo.svg" alt="" />
        </span>
        <a href="./">
          <h1>React</h1>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className="nav-end">
        <ul className="nav-links">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="click" className="button"></button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

** Footer.js **

```
import React from "react";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className="footer">
      <strong>
        <p>emeka.dev</p>
      </strong>
      <p>Copyright @emeka.dev 2022</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

** index.html **

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./scripts/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you create the react project? Are you using a transpilation tool like babel?

Comment: Didn't create a react project. Just bare vanilla js with react on top. Yes I'm using babel: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Looks like they're using Babel Standalone.

Comment: What do you think the problem is?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaMba - It looks like Babel is transpiling the code using `import` into code using `require`. But `require` isn't a standard thing on browsers, it's usually provided by a bundler of some kind. It may be possible to get Babel to leave the `import`/`export` declarations intact (not convert them), but I think you'll struggle to get those imported modules transpiled by Babel in the browser. You may want to either use React without JSX (so you don't need Babel), or use a bundler like Vite, Webpack, Rollup, Rome, ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the transform expectation to the script import
As T.J.Crowder said, it looks like babel is transpiling to use require (CommonJS)
I have not used babel standalone myself but I think you need this.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-umd
`<script src=... data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel" />`

Personally, I use the Webpack bundler so the node module resolution handles this at transpile.